# How do I log transform my y-axis in my plot? scale('log') does not work in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Here I'm making a scatterplot that contains data from 3 columns out of my dataframe. The columns are the different samples and row names are genes (thus the same for each col). I would like my y-axis to be log-transformed. However the standard way to use `yscale('log')` does not work. Some how it limits the y-axis, without making it logarithmic and data gets lost.

This is before:

```
ax = mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_02A", color="b", label="sample 02A")
    mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_04A", color="g", label="sample 04A", ax=ax)
    mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_06A", color="r", label="sample 06A", ax=ax)
    mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_08A", color="purple", label="sample 08A", ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel("gene")
    ax.set_ylabel("expression value")
    
    plt.show()
```

[image]

This is after logarithmic transformation

```
 ax = mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_02A", color="b", label="sample 02A")
mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_04A", color="g", label="sample 04A", ax=ax)
mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_06A", color="r", label="sample 06A", ax=ax)
mini_df.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_08A", color="purple", label="sample 08A", ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel("gene")
ax.set_ylabel("expression value")
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you research the documentation for `DataFrame.plot()`?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

you can just log the y-axis yourself before plotting it.
For example: (you can modify all the columns to logarithmic together instead of do it 'column by column' like my example..(

```
mini_df_copy = mini_df.copy(deep=True)
mini_df_copy.sample_02A = np.log(mini_df_copy.sample_02A)
mini_df_copy.sample_04A= np.log(mini_df_copy.sample_04A)
mini_df_copy.sample_06A= np.log(mini_df_copy.sample_06A)
mini_df_copy.sample_08A= np.log(mini_df_copy.sample_08A)

ax = mini_df_copy.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_02A", color="b", label="sample 02A")
mini_df_copy.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_04A", color="g", label="sample 04A", ax=ax)
mini_df_copy.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_06A", color="r", label="sample 06A", ax=ax)
mini_df_copy.plot(kind="scatter", x="gene",y="sample_08A", color="purple", label="sample 08A", ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel("gene")
ax.set_ylabel("expression value")
```

**Option 2:**

You can just specify the 'ylim' bounds and then no points will disappear.
ax.set_ylim((1, "max point value you want to display"))

**Option 3:**

Use 'symlog' instead of 'log': `ax.set_yscale('symlog')`

**According to the points with value 0:**
log(0) is undefined so yscale('log') modify it to None, Matplotlib just ignores the NaNs and doesn't visualize them.